# One group capture several times

Tags: regex

String:

```
A|B|CD|E(F|G|H|I)|J|K|L
```

Want:

```
F G H I
```

Tried:

```
\((?:([A-Z])\|)+([A-Z])\)
```

Result:

```
H I
```

How can one group capture several times?

Comment: What language are you using?  You might get better mileage from splitting your string on pipe (`|`).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to solve this problem through regex. TT

Comment: @WebEngine What regex flavor? Javascript, PHP, ...

Comment: If you know how many characters to capture, you can do like this: `\(([A-Z])\|([A-Z])\|([A-Z])\|([A-Z])\)`, to get all matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you better off capture the characters inside(), then split it (python 2):

```
>>> input = 'A|B|CD|E(F|G|H|I)|J|K|L'
>>> re.findall('\(([^\)]+)\)',input)[0].split('|')
['F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
```